# How to resolve domain with Direct Admin installed on a Digital Ocean VPS

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, vps, directadmin

I have a Digital Ocean VPS with an installation of Direct Admin. I have pointed my domain to 3 nameservers of Digital Ocean ( ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2, ns3 ). But when I added DNS records in DNS Management of Direct Admin to resolve my domain, nothing happened. I waited for like 9 - 10 hourse but still, I couldn't resolve my domain via Direct Admin.

Then, I added a domain zone in Digital Ocean ( using Digital Ocean control panel ) and just after 5, 6 mins, my domain was resolved.

So, the question is that, what do I have to do to manage my DNS records via Direct Admin instead of DO's control panel ?

I did submit a question on DO's Forum, and their admin replied me that if I use DO's nameservers ( ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2, ns3 ) then I have to use the control panel of Digital Ocean, but he did not tell me how to use Direct Admin instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.

To anyone who might run into the same problem like I did, you guys can try my solution:

A little explaination:

As usual, you can point a domain to a VPS by point directly that domain's A records to VPS IP, or you can point domain's DNS record to VPS Nameserver ( in my case, it's ns1.digitalocean, n2 n3, ... ).
So you can use one way or another between those 2 ways. But I didn't want that, I didn't want to manage my domain via Domain Provider or via DigitalOcean, I wanted to manage that via the DirectAdmin panel that I installed on my VPS.

So, we need another domain. For example, my domain is example.com. Now I need another domain like : examplecloud.com. Now, you point that examplecloud.com to your VPS IP, or to your VPS Nameservers, and add that domain into your DirectAdmin.
DirectAdmin automatically creates 2 nameservers for your domain ( eg. ns1.examplecloud.com, n2.examplecloud.com ). After that, you just add your example.com to DirectAdmin and point it to 2 nameservers of examplecloud.com.

That's how I completed that, you guys should try.